# TTL is inconsistent when shooting OCF with YN622 trigger system

Tags: canon, off-camera-flash, yongnuo

During my wedding receptions I like to set up 1-3 flashes in manual power mode around the room. I'd also like to have a flash in TTL mode "on camera" set to -2 or -3 exposure compensation for some front fill.

I use the YN622CT transmitter on my camera and YN685s off camera. I use a Canon 600EXRT on a bracket with a YN622 receiver so it can be triggered.

The problem I've found is that while the TTL works sometimes, most of the time the TTL is way off, more so than if the flash were connected directly to the hotshoe. The problem seems intermittent and hard to replicate consistently. My old 580ex would do a full dump every shot on this set up.

Is there something I should be setting on the trigger or the 600EXRT? The only thing I can think of is that the manual flashes are firing too early and messing with the TTL preflash but I don't know how to make the manual flashes fire after the pre flash.

At this rate I'm thinking I need to find a trigger system that can be triggered from the PC sync port of the camera so I can keep the 600EXRT on the hotshoe. The YN622 can do this with a PC to hotshoe adapter but you then can't set the power on the remote flashes and they just dump full power.

Comment: How can you use an on-camera flash with a YN-622C-TX?

Comment: This question is so full of false assumptions that I don't even know where to start. If the manual flashes were firing with preflash you wouldn't be seeing much, if any, of that light in the photo. The duration of a YN-685 is too short to still be putting out much light by the time the shutter opens *following* the pre-flash for the E-TTL flash. The YN622C-TX can be used in 'Mixed" mode where each group is controlled separately. One or more group(s) can be controlled manually while another is controlled via TTL.

Comment: @inkista With a flash bracket and a 622 receiver.

Comment: What is the angle of the flash head of the 600EX RT? Anything but straight ahead (with reference to the rest of the flash body) and the camera will assume you are bouncing it. This often results in too much power if direct flash is hitting the subject.

Comment: Ah right so preflash occurs before the shutter is open. Fair enough I was just clutching at straws. What other false assumptions am I making?

Comment: That you can't use a 622C-TX via triggering from a PC port to fire a remote flash at anything except full power. I'm sitting here and doing it right now at 1/128 with the 622C-TX not connected to anything.

Comment: I was connecting the 622tx to the camera using a non TTL hot shoe cord. Are you connecting a PC cable to the PC port on the 622tx? That might be it. I'll try it now (just have to find that cable that came with the trigger)

Comment: And why would you need a hotshoe adapter? You can run a straight PC to PC cord from the camera's PC terminal to the PC terminal on the back of the YN622C-TX.

Comment: Gotcha. Brain fart. I should have ordered a PC to PC cord instead of the hot show adaptor.